# Issue with dissolving a polygons layer in QGIS 2.4

Tags: qgis, shapefile, dissolve

I downloaded a dataset of roads and parks from OSM. I then buffered the roads and merged with the parks.
Now - all i want is to dissolve / union all the features in the merged layer.

I fail to do it using QGIS, even though a test of the same layer in ArcGIS 10.0 worked.

By failing i mean: it takes ages and creates an empty layer at the end.

When trying on a much smaller dataset from the same layer in QGIS it works, so i assume the dataset is valid.

Did anyone else face this issue?

Do you have any idea how to approach it?

Comment: Can you try to save your data in a Projected SRS (I assume that data is in epsg:4326) and retry the dissolve?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The dataset projection was already EPSG:2039 - Israel / Israeli TM Grid when i tried. I assume it should have worked.

Comment: Ok. Can you try the Topology Checker plugin (or also ST_IsValid from PostGIS)  to check for invalid geometries?

Comment: Does the "check geometry validity" from 'Vector'-->'Geometry tools' good enough? If it does - i received two issues: 56642,segments 2 and 5 of line 0 intersect at 193231.358638, 653120.298656
56642,Geometry has 1 errors.

Comment: I used also the Topology Checker plugin. It points out two invalid geometries. I'm not sure (a)why these geometries are invalid, (b)why ArcGIS manage to dissolve the features and (c)how to solve it and make the geometries valid. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try using a dissolve tool from processing Framework? I.e. with SAGA or GRASS..

Comment: Thanks. This way it worked. Now i wonder why it didn't work in the "normal" QGIS geoprocessing tools.

Comment: Well.. it is still not working. I even recreated the layer and it just doesn't work. In ArcGIS it did work though.

Comment: @doktoreas Please post your comment as an answer so we can upvote it and mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the QGIS dissolve tool fails, you can use a dissolve tool from the Processing framework (e.g. SAGA or GRASS) instead.